# Scraping a PDF File

Tags: python

[image: Please fix this error]

I am working on Scraping data from pdf file in in python . I am learning python course. I face a problem and I stuck there. I install pyMuPDF and Also install fitz. but when i run my code it give error . I upload a image of replit. In the Image error is shown. How I fix this error.

Comment: `pip install frontend`

Comment: please, consider adding code in _plain text_ form and not as an image, see [ How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)